# Authenticating with Mercurial server without supplying credentials to prompts or in .hgrc file

Tags: windows-server-2008, authentication, mercurial

I have a Windows 2008 R2 IIS7 server with Mercurial under HTTPS.  I connect to the Mercurial Repositories using TortoiseHG and via the web interface. If I don't have my username and password in the `.hgrc` file, them I'm prompted for my domain credentials.

What I want, is to setup my Mercurial repositories security in such away that I do not have to supply credentials through a basic authentication prompt or via entering them in cleartext in my personal `.hgrc` file. The user access should be inferred by being logged into the domain on the computer I am working on.

Authentication setup:

- Anonymous Authentication: Disabled
- ASP.Net Impersonation: Disabled
- Basic Authentication: Enabled
- Forms Authentication: Disabled
- Windows Authentication: Enabled

On the client side I have my credentials in my personal `.hgrc`:

```
[auth] 
tag.prefix = https://MercurialServer 
tag.username = Username 
tag.password = Password
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're asking if TortoiseHG has support for authenticating to IIS using NTLM/Kerberos to pass the Windows Authentication mode in IIS?  The answer is no; it uses the basic auth, which requires plaintext credentials, whether saved or entered.

If you were using an SSH-based protocol, it looks like there's some means to get it using GSSAPI for seamless windows auth via a supporting version of plink; [food for thought](http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn-dev/browse_thread/thread/6dec0b30b5698f05).

Comment: Hi Shane,  you hit my suspicions right on the head.  I did not think NTLM/Kereros would be supported...  I will look into the the "food for thought"... If I get any form of success I will update this thread.  On a completely different note, I wish I could put a line break in my comments.

Comment: There is this extension: https://bitbucket.org/hstuart/hg-kerberos/ -- come talk to hstuart (I'm mg) on #mercurial at http://webchat.freenode.net/